# Android Raspberry pi W/System.err(13264): java.net.ConnectException connection refused

Tags: android, tcp, raspberry-pi, iptables, netcat

Hello im new in linux and android programming , my idea is send packet data from Raspberry Pi to Android Phone via TCP socket. 
.When connection started, the data stream well , after few data sent the streaming sometimes "jammed".

My android phone IP 192.168.43.1
My static Raspberry IP 192.168.43.5

I try to change the port number but the connection still jammed, I try to reduce the size of the packet data but also still jammed .I assume the raspberry firewall (if it exist) is the problem Or maybe the iptables configuration, but how to check and disable the Raspberry firewall? just info ,in my raspberry  didn't have firestarter.  Or how to use the iptables ?

Could you help me why thats happen?or any reference would be great , thanks in advance! Here is my logcat :

```
07-30 13:11:20.731: W/System.err(13264): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.43.20 (port 12345): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
07-30 13:11:20.731: W/System.err(13264):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:118)
07-30 13:11:20.731: W/System.err(13264):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
07-30 13:11:20.731: W/System.err(13264):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
07-30 13:11:20.731: W/System.err(13264):   at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:571)
07-30 13:11:20.731: W/System.err(13264):   at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:132)
07-30 13:11:20.731: W/System.err(13264):   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:182)
07-30 13:11:20.731: W/System.err(13264):   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:154)
07-30 13:11:20.731: W/System.err(13264):   at com.uavgama.Streamingdata.Masukan(Streamingdata.java:19)
07-30 13:11:20.731: W/System.err(13264):   at com.uavgama.Adhrsparse.Keluar(Adhrsparse.java:71)
07-30 13:11:20.731: W/System.err(13264):   at com.uavgama.Adhrsparse$1.run(Adhrsparse.java:26)
07-30 13:11:20.731: W/System.err(13264):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-30 13:11:20.731: W/System.err(13264):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-30 13:11:20.731: W/System.err(13264):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-30 13:11:20.731: W/System.err(13264):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
07-30 13:11:20.731: W/System.err(13264):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 13:11:20.741: W/System.err(13264):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 13:11:20.741: W/System.err(13264):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-30 13:11:20.741: W/System.err(13264):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-30 13:11:20.741: W/System.err(13264):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 13:11:20.741: W/System.err(13264): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
07-30 13:11:20.741: W/System.err(13264):   at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
07-30 13:11:20.741: W/System.err(13264):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
07-30 13:11:20.741: W/System.err(13264):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:131)
07-30 13:11:20.741: W/System.err(13264):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:116)
07-30 13:11:20.741: W/System.err(13264):   ... 18 more
```

Here is the packed data i used to sent :

```
$909.29|34.16|160.39907|123.51508|189.56|40.42|339.78#
$62.88|52.38|32.62654|170.11087|19.19|99.57|127.72#
$847.45|65.29|128.59294|114.23773|161.92|268.55|28.90#
$957.35|48.49|142.63874|9.20948|161.73|297.63|348.33#
$634.97|25.16|105.1316|23.51827|185.56|195.88|189.1#
format :
$altitude|airspeed|lat|lon|pitch|roll|yaw#
```

this is the raspberry bash code for send the data

```
cat /home/pi/file | awk -F'\t' 'END{print}' | nc -l 12345
```

Here is my java code for data streaming:

```
 public static String Masukan() {
try {
    Socket s;
    s = new Socket("192.168.43.20", 12345);
    s.getReuseAddress();
    s.getTcpNoDelay();
    BufferedReader inp = null;
    inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    String serverMsg = null;
    serverMsg = inp.readLine();
        if ( serverMsg.endsWith("#")) {
                filter = serverMsg; 
                s.close();
            }

} catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
return filter; 

    };
```

Comment: It seems this exception is thrown in connect(). Do you by any chance connect a new socket for each transmission? Do you close your connections properly?

If you do, and there are still problems, some of your code would be useful to help you find this bug.

Comment: i use java code above to connect the socket on raspberry pi..

Comment: Yes. Please also share the android code for sending.

Comment: My android phone just receiving the packet data from Raspberry 12345 port..is my code right ?

Comment: Let me get this straight:

You _send_ data from your phone, right? You _receive_ data on the pi, right? You get the error on your phone, right? If this is all right, we need to see the code on your phone to help you.

Comment: No you wrong..I send the data stream FROM Raspberry Pi via wi-fi ,, then i want to receive that data on my android phone..at first it connected,, but sometimes jammed.. and the logcat error is came from my phone when the phone receiving the packet data from Raspberry

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your clarification. To help you, I still need to see the code where the error occurs...

Comment: thank you very much Bex.. im stuck with this for 3 weeks..

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple strange things going on here.

You might want to try the `-k` flag on netcat - it means the connection will stay.

Your awk-script seems to make sure only the last line of the file is sent. Is this intentional?

You do a rather violent hang-up in the java-code - when you got your message, you close the socket. Consider reading all of the message, filtering out what you need, and closing the socket in a `finally` block at the end. (It is always a good idea to close resources in a finally-block.)